# High Volume data processing with Resque and Redis

Tags: ruby, redis, scalability, resque, worker

I'm trying to use Resque and Redis for extremely high volume processing in a constrained amount of time.

I've used Resque and Redis before but was not using in a manner where Redis could be used to do some calculations using its core commands to speed up the calculation process prior to worker receiving its process.

I was wondering whether this approach is feasible and if so, how would we manage in a way that jobs stay as queue until it's done its own calculation in Redis daemon?